# I changed something in my configuration in visual studio code and I forgot what the default was

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just want to know what the line was before I changed it. For omniSharp configurations. In the settings.json or workspace Csharp: Unit Test Debugging Options I was editing in settings.json
The line is “csharp.unitTestDebuggingOptions”: (this is where i deleted),

}(end of code)

I accidentally deleted the code and now there's a problem saying `Value expected json(516) [Ln 66, Col1]`
I have a ubuntu os and so I had to go in and change a few things around.

Comment: Have you tried to just undo it (Ctrl+Z)? If that's not possible, are you aware you can reset settings? (instructions [here](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).) And just in case it's relevant, do you know what that error means?

Comment: you have no backup or SCM (git), go to line 66 and fix your json format, shouldn't be that difficult

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what the default value of a VS Code setting is, just search for it in the default keybindings.json (use the `Preferences: Open Default keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)).

If you want to restore something that you accidentally changed in your settings, try <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in your settings.json file. If your undo history is lost or not there (Ex. by reloading VS Code, or you were editing in the settings UI instead of settings.json), then try opening the file timeline for the [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) file (Use the `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` and `Explorer: Focus on Timeline View` commands in the command palette) to see if any record of it is saved in the timeline. If not, and you haven't done anything else to keep backups of your config files (Ex. Git repo), then I think you're out of luck.